# Display Product Combinations in Prestashop Customer View

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to get the product combinations displayed in Prestashop admin `Customer` detail view in addition to the products that are displayed for the customer.

This seems to be the relevant call from `AdminCustomersController.php` in `public form renderForm()`:

`$products = $customer->getBoughtProducts();`

Then in the `Customer` class I found the method:

```
public function getBoughtProducts()
    {
        return Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS('
        SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'orders` o
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail` od ON o.id_order = od.id_order
        WHERE o.valid = 1 AND o.`id_customer` = '.(int)$this->id);
    }
```

How can I modify this method to show the product combination alongside the product name?

I am using Prestashop version `1.6.0.9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get it using 2 ways:

1. `order_detail` table already have field 'product_name' that contains value like 'Product Name - Combination', so you can use `$products['product_name']` in that case.

or

2. if for some reason it is not good for you, same table contains also `product_attribute_id` field, it is combination id, so:

`$combination = new Combination($product['product_attribute_id']);
$attributes = $combination->getAttributesName($id_lang);
var_dump($attributes);`

will give you array of attributes that current combination contains.

Comment: How would I modify that in `AdminCustomersController`? Can I modify the line from `renderForm()` to show `$products['product_name']` instead of the line I posted in the question?

Comment: where exactly you need to show product name with combinations?

Comment: Specifically when I view a Customer in detail. I need to see the product combination as well under "Purchased Products" in that admin view.

Comment: Hi Sergii, are you able to provide some assistance in this area?

Comment: Hi Adam, I'm not sure what wrong on your side, because as I see in 1.6.1.13 (and saw in 1.6.0.9) "purchased products" table already shows products name with combination as well as mysql `order_detail` table have it too. Looks like "09/18/2014 Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts - Color : Orange, Size : S 1"